# nargs=* equivalent for options in Click

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-click

Is there an equivalent to `argparse`'s `nargs='*'` functionality for optional arguments in Click?

I am writing a command line script, and one of the options needs to be able to take an unlimited number of arguments, like:

```
foo --users alice bob charlie --bar baz
```

So `users` would be `['alice', 'bob', 'charlie']` and `bar` would be `'baz'`.

In [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs), I can specify multiple optional arguments to collect all of the arguments that follow them by setting `nargs='*'`.

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--users', nargs='*')
>>> parser.add_argument('--bar')
>>> parser.parse_args('--users alice bob charlie --bar baz'.split())
Namespace(bar='baz', users=['alice', 'bob', 'charlie'])
```

I know Click allows you to specify an argument to [accept unlimited inputs](http://click.pocoo.org/6/arguments/#variadic-arguments) by setting `nargs=-1`, but when I try to set an optional argument's `nargs` to -1, I get:

> TypeError: Options cannot have nargs < 0

Is there a way to make Click accept an unspecified number of arguments for an option?

#### Update:

I need to be able to specify options after the option that takes unlimited arguments.

#### Update:

@Stephen Rauch's answer answers this question.  However, I don't recommend using the approach I ask for here.  My feature request is [intentionally not implemented in Click](https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/484), since it can result in unexpected behaviors.  [Click's recommended approach is to use `multiple=True`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/options/#multiple-options):

```
@click.option('-u', '--user', 'users', multiple=True)
```

And in the command line, it will look like:

```
foo -u alice -u bob -u charlie --bar baz
```

Comment: @gnarlyninja I was not able to replicate this with click 8.1. Does another setting need to be enabled for this to work?

Comment: no sorry. I had a weird corner case where it was working but doesn't work across the board and I forgot to remove/edit my comment

Answer (score 35, accepted):

One way to approach what you are after is to inherit from click.Option, and customize the parser.

#### Custom Class:

```
import click

class OptionEatAll(click.Option):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.save_other_options = kwargs.pop('save_other_options', True)
        nargs = kwargs.pop('nargs', -1)
        assert nargs == -1, 'nargs, if set, must be -1 not {}'.format(nargs)
        super(OptionEatAll, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._previous_parser_process = None
        self._eat_all_parser = None

    def add_to_parser(self, parser, ctx):

        def parser_process(value, state):
            # method to hook to the parser.process
            done = False
            value = [value]
            if self.save_other_options:
                # grab everything up to the next option
                while state.rargs and not done:
                    for prefix in self._eat_all_parser.prefixes:
                        if state.rargs[0].startswith(prefix):
                            done = True
                    if not done:
                        value.append(state.rargs.pop(0))
            else:
                # grab everything remaining
                value += state.rargs
                state.rargs[:] = []
            value = tuple(value)

            # call the actual process
            self._previous_parser_process(value, state)

        retval = super(OptionEatAll, self).add_to_parser(parser, ctx)
        for name in self.opts:
            our_parser = parser._long_opt.get(name) or parser._short_opt.get(name)
            if our_parser:
                self._eat_all_parser = our_parser
                self._previous_parser_process = our_parser.process
                our_parser.process = parser_process
                break
        return retval
```

#### Using Custom Class:

To use the custom class, pass the `cls` parameter to `@click.option()` decorator like:

```
@click.option("--an_option", cls=OptionEatAll)
```

or if it is desired that the option will eat the entire rest of the command line, not respecting other options:

```
@click.option("--an_option", cls=OptionEatAll, save_other_options=False)
```

#### How does this work?

This works because click is a well designed OO framework. The `@click.option()` decorator usually instantiates a
`click.Option` object but allows this behavior to be over ridden with the cls parameter. So it is a relatively
easy matter to inherit from `click.Option` in our own class and over ride the desired methods.

In this case we over ride `click.Option.add_to_parser()` and the monkey patch the parser so that we can
eat more than one token if desired.

#### Test Code:

```
@click.command()
@click.option('-g', 'greedy', cls=OptionEatAll, save_other_options=False)
@click.option('--polite', cls=OptionEatAll)
@click.option('--other')
def foo(polite, greedy, other):
    click.echo('greedy: {}'.format(greedy))
    click.echo('polite: {}'.format(polite))
    click.echo('other: {}'.format(other))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = (
        '-g a b --polite x',
        '-g a --polite x y --other o',
        '--polite x y --other o',
        '--polite x -g a b c --other o',
        '--polite x --other o -g a b c',
        '-g a b c',
        '-g a',
        '-g',
        'extra',
        '--help',
    )

    import sys, time
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    for cmd in commands:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('-----------')
            print('> ' + cmd)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            foo(cmd.split())

        except BaseException as exc:
            if str(exc) != '0' and \
                    not isinstance(exc, (click.ClickException, SystemExit)):
                raise
```

#### Test Results:

```
Click Version: 6.7
Python Version: 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
-----------
> -g a b --polite x
greedy: ('a', 'b', '--polite', 'x')
polite: None
other: None
-----------
> -g a --polite x y --other o
greedy: ('a', '--polite', 'x', 'y', '--other', 'o')
polite: None
other: None
-----------
> --polite x y --other o
greedy: None
polite: ('x', 'y')
other: o
-----------
> --polite x -g a b c --other o
greedy: ('a', 'b', 'c', '--other', 'o')
polite: ('x',)
other: None
-----------
> --polite x --other o -g a b c
greedy: ('a', 'b', 'c')
polite: ('x',)
other: o
-----------
> -g a b c
greedy: ('a', 'b', 'c')
polite: None
other: None
-----------
> -g a
greedy: ('a',)
polite: None
other: None
-----------
> -g
Error: -g option requires an argument
-----------
> extra
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS]

Error: Got unexpected extra argument (extra)
-----------
> --help
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
  -g TEXT
  --polite TEXT
  --other TEXT
  --help         Show this message and exit.
```

Comment: This is wonderful. Thank you so much for taking the time to post this answer!

Comment: Seems like this is broken in Click v8

Comment: @KlemenTusar, I just reran the testcode with click 8.0.1 and got the exact same results as w/ 6.7 from above.  Perhaps you can write up a question documenting what you think is broken?

Comment: @StephenRauch I'm still investigating, to be honest, however, here's the GitHub issue of one of my packages that uses your solution above https://github.com/techouse/mysql-to-sqlite3/issues/15. Seems to work fine with Click 7.1.2 but not 8+. I'll keep digging and will report back :)

Comment: Seems that with Click v7.x it returns a tuple but with v8.x it returns a string.
`<class 'tuple'>
('content_files', 'content_media', 'content_usages', 'iframes')
` vs `<class 'str'> ('content_files', 'content_media', 'content_usages', 'iframes')`

Comment: Added a better description here in the Github issue https://github.com/techouse/mysql-to-sqlite3/issues/15#issuecomment-894662645

Comment: It seems it's related to this Click issue https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/2012 and simply defining declaring `type=tuple` on the click option fixes it.

Answer (score 11):

You can use this trick.

```py
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--users', nargs=0, required=True)
@click.argument('users', nargs=-1)
@click.option('--bar')
def fancy_command(users, bar):
    users_str = ', '.join(users)
    print('Users: {}. Bar: {}'.format(users_str, bar))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fancy_command()
```

Add fake `option` with a needed name and none arguments `nargs=0`, then add 'argument' with the unlimited args `nargs=-1`.

```
$ python foo --users alice bob charlie --bar baz
Users: alice, bob, charlie. Bar: baz
```

But be careful with the further options:

```
$ python foo --users alice bob charlie --bar baz faz
Users: alice, bob, charlie, faz. Bar: baz
```

Comment: But in this setup it will be possible to omit `--users` flag at all. Not sure if that is expected.

Comment: Thank you, @MarSoft! Missed that! Changed code above, adding `required=True`.
Now it's not possible to omit `---users`.

Unfortunately, the flag string can be omitted. Same results:
`$ python foo --users alice bob charlie --bar baz faz` and `$ python foo alice bob charlie --bar baz faz`

Comment: This no longer works, I get `Error: Invalid value for '--users': Takes 0 values but 3 were given`. I am using Click `8.0.1`.

Comment: See my answer with a reasonable alternative that works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75275031/95750

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue. Instead of implementing a single command line option with n number of arguments, I decided to use multiple of the same command line option and just letting Click make a tuple out of the arguments under the hood. I ultimately figured if Click didn't support it, that decision was probably made for a good reason.

https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/options/#multiple-options

here is an example of what I am saying:

instead of passing a single string argument a splitting on a delimiter:

```sh
commit -m foo:bar:baz
```

I opted to use this:

```sh
commit -m foo -m bar -m baz
```

here is the source code:

```py
@click.command()
@click.option('--message', '-m', multiple=True)
def commit(message):
    click.echo('\n'.join(message))
```

This is more to type, but I do think it makes the CLI more user friendly and robust.

Comment: This is the right answer for the interface, and the one I ultimately chose.  `nargs=+` is a nice hack, but it typically encourages bad CLI design

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I really believe that this is the correct way to use click for this behavior. Thanks for taking the time to write this answer out and post it here.

Answer (score 2):

I needed this for myself and thought of settling for the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54764354/95750) provided by @nikita-malovichko even though it is very restrictive, but it didn't work for me (see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391777/nargs-equivalent-for-options-in-click/75275031#comment132828052_54764354) to that answer) so came up with the below alternative.

My solution doesn't directly address the question on how to support `nargs=*`, but it provided a good alternative for myself so sharing it for the benefit of others.

The idea is to use one option that specifies the expected count for another, i.e., set the `nargs` count dynamically at runtime. Here is a quick demo:

```
import click


def with_dynamic_narg(cnt_opt, tgt_opt):
    class DynamicNArgSetter(click.Command):
        def parse_args(self, ctx, args):
            ctx.resilient_parsing = True
            parser = self.make_parser(ctx)
            opts, _, _ = parser.parse_args(args=list(args))
            if cnt_opt in opts:
                for p in self.params:
                    if isinstance(p, click.Option) and p.name == tgt_opt:
                        p.nargs = int(opts[cnt_opt])

            ctx.resilient_parsing = False
            return super().parse_args(ctx, args)

    return DynamicNArgSetter


@click.command(cls=with_dynamic_narg('c', 'n'))
@click.option("-c", type=click.INT)
@click.option("-n", nargs=0)
def f(c, n):
    print(c, n)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f()
```

In the above code, a custom `Command` class is created that knows the link between the "count" arg and the target arg that takes multiple args. It first does a local parsing in "resilient" mode to detect the count, then uses the count to update the `nargs` value of the target arg and then resumes parsing in normal mode.

Here is some sample interaction:

```bash
$ python t.py -c 0
0 None
$ python t.py -c 1
Usage: t.py [OPTIONS]
Try 't.py --help' for help.

Error: Missing option '-n'.
$ python t.py -c 0 -n a
Usage: t.py [OPTIONS]
Try 't.py --help' for help.

Error: Got unexpected extra argument (a)
$ python t.py -c 1 -n a
1 a
$ python /tmp/t.py -c 2 -n a b
2 ('a', 'b')
```

**Note**: The advantage over the official recommendation of using `multiple=True` is that we can use filename wildcards and let shell expand them. E.g.,

```
$ touch abc.1 abc.2
$ python t.py -c 2 -n abc.*
2 ('abc.1', 'abc.2')
$ python t.py -c $(echo abc.* | wc -w) -n abc.*
2 ('abc.1', 'abc.2')
```