# How to create option with variable number of values using Click?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

Here's what I have that does not behave as I'd like it to:

```py
import click

xmin_chlist = ['clauset', 'manual', 'percentile']


@click.command()
@click.option('-x', '--xmin', default=('clauset', None),
              type=(click.Choice(xmin_chlist), float),
              help=f'CHOICE one of {xmin_chlist}')
def get_uis(xmin):
    print(xmin)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_uis()
```

The above code is written to`ui.py`, and invoking `$ python ui.py` on the command line without specifying the `--xmin` option prints the default `('clauset', None)` as expected; so does providing 2 values to `--xmin`, such as `$ python ui.py --xmin percentile 99`.

But I'd also like to only be able to provide a single value to `--xmin`, such as `$ python ui.py --xmin clauset` and still get `None` as the default to the second value in the tuple, but instead I get the error `Error: --xmin option requires 2 arguments`. Furthermore, if possible I'd also like to be able to provide different second element defaults to `'manual'` and `'percentile'`, when they are passed alone to `--xmin` instead of just the `None` for `'clauset'`.

I tried using a callback to provide defaults based on the number of values passed to `--xmin`, but that does not appear to work either as the error prevents the callback from firing.

I understand that there is no built-in option type in Click which allows passing a variable number of values. So should I be creating my custom variable type? Or something else? What would be the best approach here?

Comment: So if I read your description correctly, you don't really want a "variable" number of values, but instead want to leave off elements at the end of a fixed length list of values and have the left off values just use default values?

Comment: @StephenRauch Yes, I believe that should also allow me achieve what I'd want. My original thinking with having an `Option` instance accept variable number of values is because both of the non-clauset `xmin` choices (namely manual and percentile) require an additional float input to work; and ideally, I'd also like for these two options to have their own defaults for this additional float value. Lastly, there is also a 4th `xmin` choices yet to be implemented which would actually require 2 additional float inputs to work. So overall, I think it'd be cleaner to allow variable # inputs.

Comment: @StephenRauch actually, this solution of yours (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48394004/5437918) does pretty much what I want, so thanks :)